# Como faço pra mudar caminho do input type="file" e enviar formulário com outra imagem?

Tags: javascript, html5, node.js, file-upload

Preciso fazer upload de várias imagens que estão dentro da minha aplicação.

Meu form é este:

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="file-field input-field offset-s4">
                    <div class="btn gradient-45deg-blue-indigo">
                        <span  id="total" >Arquivo(s)</span>
                        <input type="file" id="file" name="Imagem" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                         <input id="fileUpload" class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Escolha um ou mais imagens">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="demo-container center">

            <img id="list" class="materialboxed responsive-img" src="" alt="">

            </div>
            <img id="list2" class="materialboxed responsive-img center" src=""></img>
            <p id="imgvalor" class="center"></p>
            <button onclick="nuvem()" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light gradient-45deg-blue-indigo" id="enviar" name="action">Nuvem<i class="mdi mdi-cloud-upload left"></i></button>

        </form>
```

Este é meu array das imagens:

```
elemento=[
 'assets/cf10/f10d1.jpg',
 'assets/cf20/f20d1.jpg',
 'assets/cf30/f30d1.jpg',
 'assets/cf40/f40d1.jpg',
 'assets/cf50/f50d1.jpg'
 ]
```

Após ter meu array, uso essa função para transformar as imagens em base64:

```
const toDataURL = url => fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result)
    reader.onerror = reject
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
  }))
```

Em seguida, chamo a função que irá mudar a imagem na minha tag html:

```
var imgmudar = 
toDataURL(elemento[2])
  .then(dataUrl => {
    document.getElementById('list').src = dataUrl; 
  })
```

Agora que tenho a imagem carregada no DOM, posso usar a minha função que faz um processamento local:

```
    var tempototloc;
    function tempoLocal() {
        var fim = new Date().getTime();
        var tempo = fim - inicio;
        var d = new Date();
        tempototloc = tempo;

        document.getElementById('TempoExec').value = tempo +' ms';
        document.getElementById('OndeProc').value = 'Local';
        document.getElementById('DataExec').value = d.getDate() +'/'+ (d.getMonth()+1)+'/'+d.getFullYear()+' '+d.getHours()+':'+d.getMinutes()+':'+d.getSeconds();

                $('#enviarDados').ajaxForm({
                    url:'/enviar/dados',
                    type:'post',
                        success: function(data){                         
                        }
                }).submit();    
                swal('Foram encontradas '+contface+ ' face(s)', 'O tempo Local foi de '+tempototloc+' ms', 'success');

    }

    var inicio;
    var contface = 0;
    function local() {
    inicio = new Date().getTime();

    (function(){
    var img = document.getElementById('list');
        var tracker = new tracking.ObjectTracker(['face']);
        tracker.setStepSize(1.7);
        tracking.track('#list', tracker);
        var face = [];
        var i = 0;
        tracker.on('track', function(event) {
            event.data.forEach(function(rect) {
            window.plot(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
            i++;
            face[i] = rect.x + '-' +rect.y;            
            });

            document.getElementById('contar').innerHTML = i+' faces encontradas';
            contface = i;
        });

        window.plot = function(x, y, w, h) {
            var rect = document.createElement('div');
            document.querySelector('.demo-container').appendChild(rect);
            rect.classList.add('rect');
            rect.style.width = w + 'px';
            rect.style.height = h + 'px';
            rect.style.left = (img.offsetLeft + x) + 'px';
            rect.style.top = (img.offsetTop + y) + 'px';
        };


        }());
    setTimeout(tempoLocal, -1);


    }                 


    $('#file').click(function(){
            $('.rect').removeAttr('style');
            $('#imgvalor').html("");
        });
```

Ate aqui, tudo bem, o problema é quando vou submeter o formulário para o servidor, a imagem não é lida (não sei se porque estou usando um input type="file") pois quando eu carrego a imagem manualmente consigo realizar a função abaixo, mas quando faço essa mudança da imagem através das funções anteriores não funciona, é como se não carregasse em algum lugar essa informação para o form enviar para o servidor.

Minha função de envio para o servidor é essa:

```
     var time1 = 0;
     var time2 = 0;
     var contfaceserv = 0;
function serverdet(){
                $('#uploadForm').ajaxForm({

                    url:'/upload',
                    type:'post',
                    success: function(data){
                    $('#imgvalor').html(data.msg);
                    $('#list').attr('src', data.file);
                    $('#contar').html(data.qtdface);
                    $('#faces').html(data.arrface);
                    contfaceserv = data.qtdface;
                    dadosnuvem();
                }

           });


}


function dadosnuvem(){
    time2 = new Date().getTime();
    var time3 = time2 - time1;
    var d = new Date();

    document.getElementById('TempoExec').value = time3 +' ms';
            document.getElementById('OndeProc').value = 'Nuvem';
            document.getElementById('DataExec').value = d.getDate() +'/'+ (d.getMonth()+1)+'/'+d.getFullYear()+' '+d.getHours()+':'+d.getMinutes()+':'+d.getSeconds();

                    $('#enviarDados').ajaxForm({
                        url:'/enviar/dados',
                        type:'post',
                            success: function(data){

                            }
                    }).submit(); 
                    swal('Foram encontradas '+contfaceserv+ ' face(s)', 'O tempo na Nuvem foi de '+time3+' ms', 'success');
}

        function nuvem(){
            time1 = new Date().getTime();
            serverdet();

        }
```

Tenho também essa função que realizar a leitura do arquivo ao ser realizado o evento no file:

```
(function() {

     function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        let files = evt.target.files; // Lista de Arquivos

        // Laço para pegar lista de arquivos e renderizar os Previews
        for (var file of files) {

            // Somente irá processar se for imagem
            if (!file.type.match('image.*')) {
                continue;
            }

            var imagem = new Image(); //Instancia do Objeto Image acessar imagens
            var reader = new FileReader(); //Instancia do FileReader acessar arquivos

            // Função para percorrer informações dos arquivos
            reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                // Renderizando Previews
                imagem.src = theFile.target.result;

                //var span = document.createElement('span');

                var nome = `${theFile.target.result}`;

                var output = [];

                imagem.onload = function() {

                var height = this.height,
                     width = this.width;

                     document.querySelector('.arquivo').innerHTML = `<ul>${file.type || 'n/a'}</ul>`;
                     document.querySelector('.tamanho').innerHTML = `<ul>${file.size+' bytes' || 'n/a'}</ul>`;
                     document.querySelector('.dimensao').innerHTML = `<ul>${width}x${height}</ul>`;

                     document.getElementById('TipoStatus').value = file.type ? file.type : 'n/a';
                     document.getElementById('TamStatus').value = file.size ? file.size + ' bytes' : 'n/a';
                     document.getElementById('DimStatus').value =  width +'x'+height;


                let result = `<li><b> -  bytes - </b>`;

                //document.getElementById('#list').insertBefore(span, null);
                document.getElementById('list').src = nome;

                }
            });

            // Ler arquivo da imagem com uma URL.
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, true);


}());
```

Sei que meu código está bagunçado, mas eu preciso automatizar esse processo de envio, pois manualmente apesar de conseguir acaba sendo muito demorado.

Vi uso de promisses, mas não estou sabendo montar a lógica de uma forma ssícrona **(imagem1 -> local() e depois nuvem() -> imagem 2...)**, por isso estou tentando fazer utilizando um array das imagens e depois chamando a função local() e outra nuvem() para cada imagem que tenho na minha lista do array. Como consigo realizar a façanha de carregar a imagem, e chamar minhas funções para cada uma delas?

Comment: Se eu usasse um select direito para mudar a imagem a ser utilizada, conseguiria realizar a minha função? Pois, como estou usando input="file" talvez ele preciso do evento de escolha manual para guardar na memória para enviar (suponho).